# Algorithmic way of declaring buffers of certain size

Tags: algorithm

What is the algorithmic **convention** for declaring a buffer, say`M` of size `n`? I am hesitated to use something like `M = {size of n}`. I have scanned this [document](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4471-5173-9%2F1.pdf) but nothing mention about this. Is there a better neat way?

Answer (score 0):

In the document you provided, table A.3: `|S| cardinality of S`.

Comment: cardinality means the size, isn't it?

Comment: it's a count of elements in the set, you can add equality or range constraint to it